# NSDictionary and warning about "pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, warnings, nsdictionary

I see that there is a bunch of posts on this topic, but a solution is not clicking in my head.  Here is my issue:

```
double var = [[variables objectForKey:[value characterAtIndex:1]] doubleValue];
```

variables is an `NSDictionary`. `value` in this situation is an `NSString` and I need `characterAtIndex:1` because I prepended the string with a special designator. In English, I want to get a value from my `NSDictionary` based on this `NSString` key, but I get this warning when building:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'objectForKey:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: Do you have some examples of `value`? I have a feeling that you are trying to remove the first character of the string before using it as a key, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`characterAtIndex:` returns a unichar, not an object, while NSDictionary keys must be objects. It sounds like you want something like `[value substringToIndex:1]`.